# VM Player: is it possible to create snapshots?

Tags: virtualization

I am currently using VMPlayer to host Windows 2008/SharePoint 2010.  I created a virtual environment and I would like the ability to revert to snapshots or restore points.
Is this possible?

Comment: this should be migrated to superuser it'd be good there

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, VMWare Player won't allow that.

From their [FAQ page](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html):

> **How does VMware Player compare to VMware Workstation and VMware ACE?**
>
> VMware Player enables you to quickly and easily create and run virtual machines. However, VMware Player lacks many powerful features, such as Teams, multiple Snapshots and Clones, or Virtual Rights Management features for end-point security found in VMware Workstation and VMware ACE.

Comment: Not entirely true. You can do [what Leith suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591419/1954860). Pausing/suspending the VM in fact makes a snapshot. If you copy that VM state, you can use that again later on.

Comment: It's a workaround, but I'd bet your snapshot will have the size of a full image, where real snapshots are differential. Not to mention the additional hassle of having to wire things up on the file system every time you want to save or restore a snapshot.

Answer (score 59):

You can just pause the VM and make a copy the VM folder.

Comment: This solution was sufficient for my needs. Though you need to make sure you have the extra disk space for coping the entire vm dir.

Comment: What folder should I be copying, assuming default installations of VMware Player, and the VM images are located at `C:\VMs`?

Answer (score 4):

You can mange snapshots with command line tool **vmrun** which comes with VmWare workstation. You do not need to run workstation and buy it. You can just install it and use vmRun for snapshots and VmWare Player for running VM

Comment: Are you sure? I have VMWare player 6 installed, and I just installed VMWare VIX, which includes vmrun.exe.
When I run the snapshot command, I get this error:
Error: The operation is not supported.
My Command:
vmrun.exe -T player snapshot "E:\path_to_file.vmx" mySnapshot

Comment: snapshots are not supported in VMWare player, so using vmrun is out of the picture. I suggest you [pause the VM and copy that state] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20591419/206725)